# How to compare Multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Have look Please i have 2 arrays array1 and array2 i want to compare these arrays and need the array back which is not exist in array2.
I really to resolve this issue i am working on app.
So kindly help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in Advance. 
Here is array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 4
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )
)
```

Here is array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 4
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )
)
```

I need result like this

Result Array

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_type] => user
            [canvas_id] => 1
            [canvas_mac] => 123.234.232.121
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try array_udiff (http://php.net/array_udiff). Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: I don't think so it would work for me because the method you mentioned above its multiplying the object values and making comparison but i have alphabets in my array too an as well as i need the same value on other array too no difference like 
above method even taking equal to this 
height = 2, width = 4
height = 4, width = 2
above method said its equal but i need it same like this
height = 2, width = 4
height = 2, width = 4
Now it is equal